# Having trouble with the relationship of Vendors supplying a Factory with Ingredients relationship in ER diagram

Tags: sql, erd

[Unsure of how I should relate ingredients and Vendors to a factory, a single Vendor supplies a single factory with many ingredients.]

[image: 1]

Comment: I would guess through a recipe (like pretzels). I would also tie pretzels to a factory and not workers.

Comment: @KeithL what would I do with workers than? how would I relate them to the operations?

Comment: they work at a factory

Comment: It is difficult to know how to answer your questions without context.

Comment: @KeithL srry ty okay so here are the business rules. Vendors supplies the factory with ingredients, workers work at the factory and create pretzels buyers/retail buys the pretzels. That's the schematic in play

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Vendor and factory can be of One-to-One relationship.
2. Vendor and Ingredients can be of One-to-Many relationship.

[ERD Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WNkj.png)

Comment: how does the Vendor supply the factory with ingredients if not directly connected?